# Insert line break if there are more than one space in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to insert a line break in Python, If I encounter more than 1 space in my text, I want to replace with one space and a line break. I have my data in excel cell. This is how my code looks like,

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def excelcleaner(textstring):
    return textstring.replace("  ","\n")

df = pd.read_excel("lbook.xlsx")
df["clean_content"] = df["uncleaned_content"].apply(excelcleaner)
df.to_excel("lbook.xlsx")
```

Right now, it replaces the specified spaces (Now its 2) with a line break. How can I modify it, so that it detects the number of spaces and replaces with a single line break.

Comment: So any number of spaces more than one should be replaced with `'\n'`?

Comment: Yes! Thats how I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` from the regex module:

```py
import re

def excelcleaner(textstring):
    # This will find any 2 or more spaces and replace with a newline char
    return re.sub('\s{2,}', '\n', textstring)

mystr = "abc 123  efg   111"
print(excelcleaner(mystr))

abc 123
efg
111
```

In case you aren't familiar with regex syntax, `\s` is a whitespace character and `{<min>, <max>}` is a range indicator. `{2,}` says find two or more occurrences

Comment: Keep in mind that `\s` means any whitespace character, so such `re.sub` will also change for example `\n\n\n` to `\n`

Comment: @Daweo True, I'm assuming if OP is iterating over lines from a file or entries in a DataFrame that shouldn't be too much of a problem, but good to keep in mind